# Store jQuery in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've got an FAQ page I'm building. Next to the question, there is a plus sign to expand the content. On click, I've added the class active, but there are many questions, and I don't want to repeat the same jQuery snippet for each question. I've figured out how to find the parent ID but I'm having trouble storing it in an variable to reuse in the jQuery script.

What I want to be able to do:

```
var element = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id')

$('.expand').click(function(){ 
$('element .expand').toggleClass('active')
})
```

Is there a way to do this? I get undefined when I do this:

```
$('.expand').click(function(){
    console.log(element)
});
```

Comment: You either have to pass element to the function - `$('.expand').click(function(element)`, or you can simply use the `this` keyword

Comment: assuming line #1 here is at the document level, you are essentially saying `$(window).parent().parent().attr("id")`, which obviously will return undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `find()` function to locate children of a selected element:

```
var element = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id')
$('.expand').click(function(){ 
    $("#" + element).find('.expand').toggleClass('active')
});
```

However, looking at your code, it seems like you just want to toggle the "active" class of the clicked element. If that is the case, you can do this much more simply without a variable at all:

```
$('.expand').click(function(){ 
    $(this).toggleClass('active')
});
```

Comment: This is it! I knew there was a simpler way. Thank you @americanulaut!

Comment: It should be `$('#' + element)`. You need the `#` prefix to indicate it's an ID.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, I overlooked that she was grabbing the ID rather than a reference to the element itself.